# Bootstrap Switch fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I'm trying to add bootstrap switch to a rails project. When I add my script from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-switch) as this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

I end up getting an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at bootstrap-switch.js:743
    at bootstrap-switch.js:19
    at bootstrap-switch.js:22
```

And the fn that's highlighted red as an issue is here:

```
$.fn.bootstrapSwitch = function (option) {
    for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = Array(_len2 > 1 ? _len2 - 1 : 0), _key2 = 1; _key2 < _len2; _key2++) {
      args[_key2 - 1] = arguments[_key2];
    }
```

Any ideas why that isn't found? Or does anyone have a link to a bootstrap-switch.js file that I can use that will work?

Thanks!

I also tried using the [bootstrap-switch gem](https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/bootstrap-switch-rails) but that was giving me a different error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most common reason behind this type of error is, not having JQuery loaded before this plugin script. Make sure you have added that CDN version of `bootstrap-switch.js` after the JQuery.

I mean like following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Comment: ended up pulling in my rails javascript after this... embarrassing. good catch.